# How do i remove rows based on comma-separated list of values in a Power BI parameter in Power Query?

Tags: f#, powerbi, powerquery, m

I have a list of data with a title column (among many other columns) and I have a Power BI parameter that has, for example, a value of "a,b,c". What I want to do is loop through the parameter's values and remove any rows that begin with those characters.

For example:

```
Title
a
b
c
d
```

Should become

```
Title
d
```

This comma separated list could have one value or it could have twenty. I know that I can turn the parameter into a list by using

```
parameterList = Text.Split(<parameter-name>,",")
```

but then I am unsure how to continue to use that to filter on. For one value I would just use

```
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Table", each Text.StartsWith([key], <value-to-filter-on>))
```

but that only allows one value.

EDIT: I may have worded my original question poorly. The comma separated values in the parameterList can be any number of characters (e.g.: a,abcd,foo,bar) and I want to see if the value in [key] starts with that string of characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `List.Contains` to check whether the starting character is in the parameter list.

```
each List.Contains(parameterList, Text.Start([key], 1)
```

---

**Edit:** Since you've changed the requirement, try this:

```
Table.SelectRows(
    #"Table",
    (C) => not List.AnyTrue(
                   List.Transform(
                       parameterList,
                       each Text.StartsWith(C[key], _)
                    )
                )
 )
```

For each row, this transforms the `parameterList` into a list of `true/false` values by checking if the current `key` starts with each text string in the list. If any are true, then `List.AnyTrue` returns true and we choose not to select that row.

Comment: So I'm trying this and my query has gone from taking less than 2 seconds to taking minutes long and then failing out with an out of memory exception. While I think this solution may work in theory, in practice it seems like it is very slow (there are only around 3000 rows in this table so I'm surprised it's running so slowly), unless I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: That's odd. Not sure if it will help or not but I'd try saving the list into memory before using it in the select rows line: `parameterList = List.Buffer(Text.Split(<parameter-name>,","))`

Comment: Okay, this was actually my bad - I accidentally added a line that was causing an infinite call. So, I may have worded my original question poorly. The comma separated values in the parameterList can be any number of characters (e.g.: a,abcd,foo,bar) and I want to see if the value in [key] starts with that string of characters. Is there a way to modify this to work for that case?

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to filter out all the values from the parameter, you can use something like:

```
= Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each List.Contains(Parameter1,Text.Start([Title],1))=false)
```

Another way to do this would be to create a custom column in the table, which has the first character of title:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "FirstChar", each Text.Start([Title],1))
```

and then use this field in the filter step:

```
= Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each List.Contains(Parameter1,[FirstChar])=false)
```

I tested this with a small sample set and it seems to be running fine. You can test both and see if it helps with the performance. If you are still facing performance issues, it would probably be easier if you can share the pbix file.

Comment: I just added a new EDIT to the bottom of my question to add a bit more clarity. My parameters aren't always single characters and can be of varying length. Is it possible to make this work for that use case?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work fairly well:

```
= List.Select(Source[Title], each Text.Contains(Parameter1,Text.Start(_,1))=false)
```

Replace *Source* with the name of your table and *Parameter1* with the name of your Parameter.

Comment: I apologize - I may have worded my question a bit poorly. I have updated it with more information in an edit at the bottom.